# Azure CLI Get Current Subscription details

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How do I find the current Azure subscription using Azure CLI.

az account list only gives me the list of subscriptions.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use `az account show` to do it, if you do not specify the property, it gets the the details of the current subscription.

[image]

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-show).

Answer (score 14):

You can run : `az account list -o table`.

The output will be a list of resources in table form.
The details of your current subscription will be on line with `IsDefault = True`.
Highlighted in green in the figure below.[image]